# IOS swift how to load pictures in a TableView all at once (i.e. before scrolling)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a TableView with several pictures and a full screen "waiting view". I know that the standard behaviour of the TableView is to load the visible pictures, the other pictures are loaded only when the user scrolls to see them.

What I want is to hide my "waiting view" only when all the pictures in the TableView have been loaded, so I need to load the pictures all at once. How can I do this?

Comment: Cells that are not visible do not even exist, so what does “load” even mean here?

Comment: For instance is it possible to tell the TableView to create a specific number of cells instead of the visible cells only?

Comment: Why would you want to?

Answer (score 0):

A table view is a "window" into a set of data that might be bigger than the number of cells you can see at one time. The data is the model, and the table view's data source fetches data from the model and installs it in cells as needed to display the currently visible cells.

The data model for a table view is often an array, or it might be an array of arrays for a sectioned table view. (You can certainly use other storage methods for your model, but arrays are quite common.)

If you want to load all the pictures that will be displayed into your table view, you should display your full screen waiting view, populate all of the items in your model with pictures, and only switch to the table view when all the pictures have been loaded.

Note that if you have a lot of items in your table view's model, you might have more pictures than can fit in memory at once. In that case you may want to save all of your pictures as files in your documents or caches directory, and put URLs to the images in your data model. Loading images from disk is fairly fast compared to downloading them from the internet, and that will prevent you from running out of memory and crashing.